# Jasper Report, REPORT_LOCALE manuall passing via SpagoBI

Tags: jasper-reports, spagobi

Does anybody know how to manually pass REPORT_LOCALE param via SpagoBI or, at least, how to manually pass REPORT_LOCALE parameter for Jasper?

What I want to achieve is that I can dynamically pass language parameter, so my reports can be generated in different languages.

Does anybody know how to do this? I use SpagoBI for calling Jasper Reports via SpagoBI REST 2.0 API, but I'm not so sure is this SpagoBI or Jasper issue.

I tried to define REPORT_LOCALE, language, userLocale, reportLocale params in SpagoBI (passed es_ES, es, [es, ES], es,ES), but it didn't work. I also tried to use userLocale, reportLocale in Jasper (the same values as above), but also without success.

When I switch language in SpagoBI, it works, but I need to call report via REST, so this is not workaround for me, but if I could switch language in REST, maybe I can do some business.

Also, REPORT_LOCALE in Jasper works, but I can do nothing with it, I need that REST call.

Can anybody tell me more about this?

edit: Setting locale in iReport is not solution, it works when you are making report, but when you want to call it via SpagoBI it's compeltelly different story.

Comment: Did the duplicate answer your doubts or are you still having issues.

Comment: No, that topic is about how to change locale in iReports, and I need to pass locale as parameter to Jasper from SpagoBI.

Comment: No it's not about to change in ireport, its about how you pass it in parameter map when you fill the report... I guess you have parameter map in SpagoBI as well...

Comment: This maybe can help you http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v56/report-locales, see the local attribute

Comment: Thank you for you answers, but I'm afraid it is not what I'm looking for. I must use SpagoBI API to pass this parameter, so java code or XML is out for me. 

I already tried to define some params in Jasper (reportLocale, userLocale), hoping that if SpagoBI passes them, locale will really change, but I had no luck.